# How to save 16-Bit I/Q interleaved samples of a waveform to binary file using Octave?

Tags: matlab, octave

I need to generate a binary file using GNU Octave or Matlab, the data in that file is 16 bit interleaved I/Q data (16 bit real component, 16 bit imaginary component) of a waveform.

Say the generated file is called "output.bin", and if we read bit [0:15] as little endian, we'll get the "I" of the first sample; bit[16:31] is the "Q" of the first sample;

bit[32:47] -> I of the second sample

bit[48:63] -> Q of the second sample

. . . . . .

All I could found is something like this:

```
points = 1000;

% Determines the frequency offset from the carrier
cycles = 101;
phaseInc = 2*pi*cycles/points;
phase = phaseInc * (0:points-1);

% Create an IQ waveform
Iwave = cos(phase);
Qwave = sin(phase);
IQData = Iwave+1i*Qwave;
IQData = IQData(:)';

save -binary output.bin IQData
```

. . . . . .

But apparently what I'll get from this is not 16-bit interleaved I/Q data.

I'm new to Octave/Matlab, really couldn't figure it out.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How do you imagine the output file to look like?Are you just looking for a way to save the `IQData` for future re-use? Or do you need an output file with a specific format?

Comment: For a binary file containing 16 bits values you'll need to know which [endianess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) (big endian or little endian) the reader of the file will use.

Comment: It is not clear where the 16-bits comes into your code, since what you have shown will be 64-bit double. Are you trying to write some type of 16-bit floating point value such as half precision or bfloat16?  Or some type of scaled 16-bit integer?  Please clarify.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou Thanks! I added some more information about the file I need. I'll need it for future re-use.

Comment: Thanks @Hoki! It's little endian.

Comment: Thanks @JamesTursa! Sorry I didn't make it clear. I'm trying to write some complex numbers eg: 1.23 + 4.56i with both real (1.23) and imaginary (4.56) parts are 16 bit precision float. I just explained bit more in my post.

Comment: As far as I know, the language does not have built-in support for a 16-bit _float_. May I ask how exactly you represent such a type in octave/matlab? If you mean to say that you'll represent your signal as a uint16, then this changes things. Also, at the risk of sounding simplistic, since you haven't made this 100% clear, you are _not_ just trying to find a way to save this data for future re-use in a separate session, are you? (if so, the answer to your question is simply "use `save` and `load`"). Perhaps it would shed some light if you described why this specific format is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MATLAB, see fopen( ) and fwrite( ) for writing out binary files. For R2018a and later, your IQData will already be in interleaved format so you can write directly, but you may need this helper routine:

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/77530-freadcomplex-and-fwritecomplex

For R2017b and earlier you would need to copy the data to get it in interleaved format before you did the writing. E.g., this would get the real & imag data into interleaved format (as a real variable):

```
Data = [Iwave;Qwave];
```

Then write Data to the output file.  In fact, if you were not worried about that extra data copy, this interleaved Data method will work in all versions of MATLAB.

For conversion to 16-bit floating point, some options are:

Half Precision: Use the MATLAB function half( ) to convert from double to half precision (R2018b or later).
https://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ref/half.html

If you have R2018a or earlier you will have to convert to half precision manually.  C Code to do this is given here:
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23173-ieee-754r-half-precision-floating-point-converter

bfloat16:  There is no official MATLAB support for this yet.  A simple truncated method to get you close (i.e., without the round-to-even and without NaN checking) would be to convert to single precision and then pick off the most significant 16-bits for writing. E.g., something like

```
u16 = typecast(single(Data),'uint16');
b16 = u16(1:2:end);
```

Then write b16 to your binary file.